# where to perform request parameters data type conversion: Controller or Model?

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller, model, controller

In a MVC application, where to perform request parameters data type conversion: Controller or Model?

For example I have 3 parameters coming with request: user_name, password, role_id. So I receive all 3 of them as string in the **Controller**. This is for example the **Controller** code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String userName = request.getParameter("user_name");
      String password = request.getParameter("password");
      String roleId = request.getParameter("role_id");
   }
}
```

The 3rd parameter has to be treated as an integer. So I have 2 choices:

1. convert it into an integer first in the **Controller** and then pass it to the **Model**.

In this case this is the **Controller** code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String userName = request.getParameter("user_name");
      String password = request.getParameter("password");
      String roleId = request.getParameter("role_id");
      int roleIdN = Integer.parseInt(roleId);
      MyService myService = new MyService();
      boolean result = myService.login(userName, password, roleIdN);
      ...
   }
}
```

And this is the **Model** code:

```
public class MyService {
   public boolean login(String userName, String password, int roleId) {
      ...
   }
}
```

2. pass it to the **Model** as String; the **Model** will convert it into an integer before using it.

In this case this is the **Controller** code:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String userName = request.getParameter("user_name");
      String password = request.getParameter("password");
      String roleId = request.getParameter("role_id");
      MyService myService = new MyService();
      boolean result = myService.login(userName, password, roleId);
      ...
   }
}
```

And this is the **Model** code:

```
public class MyService {
   public boolean login(String userName, String password, String roleId) {
      int roleIdN = Integer.parseInt(roleId);
      ...
   }
}
```

Where it makes the most sense? I am trying to figure out the boundaries of both **Controller** and **Model**. What if the 3rd parameter does not contain a number?

### Update

AFAIK these are the checks:
(a) The parameters exist in the request.
(b) The parameters are not null or empty.
(c) The parameters can be converted to their respective correct data type.
(d) The parameters exist in correct range for example role_id should be a number between 1 to 4.

Which of these checks should be in **Controller** and which in **Model**? 
Only for (a) I am sure that it should be in **Controller**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about what is the representation that makes the most sense in your domain and use that for your model. Let the controller adapt the string representation it receives to the model data type.

So in your example, the controller should be responsible for converting to an int, and returning malformed requests in case it's not receiving an int.

Update:
As a rule of thumb you want to construct your domain objects as valid so I would do all of these checks before the boundary of your domain. In a sense they're part of the world "outside" your domain. They are linked to the external representation of your model, in this case as http parameters

Comment: I have made some modifications in the question. Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: See my answer in the post